# Forward port to OpenVPN Client

Tags: port-forwarding, iptables, openvpn

I have an `OpenVPN` server on my vps running. Now I want to forward some specific ports to my clients. I have already added some rules to my `iptables`without any success. Maybe someone can have a look.

[image: iptables]

IP - Forwarding is already enabled

```
sysctl -w net.ipv4.ip_forward=1
```

Thanks!

Comment: Sureley there’s no need to censor the addresses because they’re supposed to be VPN-internal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I know what was wrong:

- I had more than one `VPNClient` with the same `IPAddress`. So I gave each of them a static `IPAddress`

> Define a directory where the client scripts should be stored , e.g. /etc/openvpn/staticclients and create the directory
>
> ```
> mkdir /etc/openvpn/staticclients
> ```
>
> Add this directory as option to your openvpn configfile at the server:
>
> ```
> client-config-dir /etc/openvpn/staticclients
> ```
>
> For each client you have to create a file. The filename must match the `common name` attribute that was specified at the certificate of the client. This command gets the CN from the computers certificate:
>
> This example pushs the `IPAddress` 10.1.134.110/10.1.134.109 to the Client with the `common name` **TESTCLIENT** and also pushes a additional route for subnet 10.1.135.0.
>
> ```
> cat /etc/openvpn/staticclients/TESTCLIENT
>
> ifconfig-push 10.1.134.110 10.1.134.109
> push "route 10.1.135.0 255.255.255.0 10.1.134.62"
> ```

- http://www.yougetsignal.com/tools/open-ports/ and http://canyouseeme.org/ didn't correctly detects the ports. I had to additionally start my application on the client, that the websites were able to see these ports.
- No need of additionally `SNAT` rules. Only these rules were needed:

> ```
> sysctl -w net.ipv4.ip_forward=1
>
> iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp --dport 28006 -j DNAT --to 10.1.134.110
> ```